# Unit 'CodeSiteLogging' not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

On Delphi XE7 I have on Tools> Options >library path U:\Program Files (x86)\Raize\DM2\Lib\RS-XE7\Win32 to run code for codesite.

The code is running but I upgrade the code to XE10 seattle.

Now I get an error F2613 Unit 'CodeSiteLogging' not found.
I'm confuse that there is no path like U:\Program Files (x86)\Raize\DM2\Lib\RS-XE10Seattle\Win32

Must I set the same path like XE7 on XE10 seattle?

Comment: Did you choose to install CodeSite express when you installed Seattle?

Comment: I think no (install was 2 months ago), but I can't see CodeSite on thirtparty. I didn't install android sdk. But I did not see a popup about CodeSite express.

Comment: According to here (https://www.embarcadero.com/products/codesite#tryit) you should see a CodeSite option in the Tools menu. If you don't then I guess you did not install it. Try to modify the installation to add it.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I reinstall D10Seattle, nothing found about CodeSite Express in the installation procedure. But I could install it with GETIT.

Comment: Embarcadero's website says, "CodeSite Express is included with RAD Studio, Delphi, and C++Builder"! Seems like they don't know their own product!

Answer (score 3):

To get CodeSite Express I must install the tool with GetIT.

Through Tools> GetIt Package Manager...
select CodeSite Express 5.2.1 and click install.

Comment: is a CodeSite installer available somewhere? i need to install it on my offline Delphi workstation.

Comment: When I install with GetIT, I found the install on C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\CatalogRepository\CodeSite_5_Express_RX10

Comment: In Delphi 11.0 the package location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Raize\CS5\Bin\CodeSiteExpressPkg_Design280.bpl